# Change login error messages

Tags: errors

took a look at the questions but I couldn`t find a similar one.

I need to change the custom error messages that are displayed when user tries to login with a wrong username or password.

Like, change this: "**ERROR**: The password you entered for the username **%1$s** is incorrect. Lost your password?" to this "Wrong information" (just an example)

I tried to use the "add_filter" but I`m not familiar with it, so, any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, the comment above by user20986 is spam.  It takes you to a page that tells you that your flash software is out of date and needs to be updated.  Recommend that admins remove the comment by user20986

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can do that using `login_errors` filter hook and here is how:

```
add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

function login_error_message($error){
    //check if that's the error you are looking for
    $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
    if (is_int($pos)) {
        //its the right error so you can overwrite it
        $error = "Wrong information";
    }
    return $error;
}
```

### update:

i just tested the code and it works fine just pasted the code in my theme's functions.php file without changing anything with the .po file

[image]

Comment: Just to make everything clear, I should replace 'incorrect' with the error string? By the way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just tried this way and it doesn`t work, but I`m not sure if the wordpress .po file is overwriting the text. Any ideas?

Comment: the text from WordPress.po is served before that filter hook is fired, and no you don't have to change `incorrect`, its checking if the error message contains that word.

Comment: I tried to put this to work but I couldn`t. I actually even tried to remove the conditional part, so it should return the text in the $error variable right? But it has no effect. 

Digging the .po file I saw that the messages I want to overwrite are located in the wp-includes/user.php file like: "<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty."

Comment: @Vitor you are doing something wrong, there is no need to touch the .po file, i updated my answer.

Comment: Please change `strpos` with `stripos` that is case insensitive; it is important because error messages are some like "Error: Invalid Username."