# Custom Log In Screen - Disable password recovery

Tags: customization, login, password, account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change login error messages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages)

I'm creating a custom log in page on a wordpress install and would like to remove the "Lost your password?" link from the "ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?" message that comes up if the user inserts the wrong password.

I've been looking in the wp-login.php but must be missing something, can someone point me to the right file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the generated text in the `wp-includes\user.php` file so removed it there and done what I was looking for.

Comment: It's not advisable to change core files (this will be lost with an update, and potentially mean plug-ins do not function properly). See the related question on how to do this without modifying the core files.