# Custom Login Errors and variables I can use

Tags: filters, login

I need to change this error message from including the username to the users email address.

I've checked this question and answer out and it helped, but didn't go far enough for me.
[Change login error messages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages)

I took this code from the `wp_includes/user.php` core file and I know that I can use the filter `login_errors` to override this message. My question is what variables do I have access to in this filter? How do I switch this out for the email?

`'<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?'`

Here's what I have so far, but I don't know what variable I need to use to get it working.

```
add_filter('login_errors','cc_login_error_message');

function cc_login_error_message($error){
    //check if that's the error you are looking for
    $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
    if (is_int($pos)) {
        //its the right error so you can overwrite it
        $error = sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ), $user_email, wp_lostpassword_url() );
    }
    return $error;
}
```

Any ideas?

Specifically the $user_email variable in my script returns nothing, I'm not sure if there is such a variable, but that one I just made up.

Comment: This also doesn't work, I'm assuming because `current_user` isn't signed in yet.
`$current_user->user_email`

Comment: This filter does not pass any user information with it. Since the user failed to log in, there is no user data available from WordPress, except in the WP_Error object, which is not available in this filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this, but you could rewrite the `wp_authenticate_username_password()` function in the `\wp-includes\class-wp-error.php` file.

Of course you cannot edit the function directly, but since this function is a filter function, you can remove the filter, copy it, add the copied function back in and test it. After testing that it still produces the same error, you can then change the error in the copied code.

The following code removes the old WordPress function and creates a new function with a unique name.

```
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password' );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_115539_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
/**
 * Remove Wordpress filer and write our own with changed error text.
 */
function wpse_115539_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') )
        return $user;

    if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
            return $user;

        $error = new WP_Error();

        if ( empty( $username ) )
            $error->add( 'empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty.' ) );

        if ( empty( $password ) )
            $error->add( 'empty_password', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.' ) );

        return $error;
    }

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

    if ( !$user )
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="%s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ), wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    $user = apply_filters( 'wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        return $user;

    if ( ! wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) )
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ),
        $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    return $user;
}
```

The next step is to test the code to make sure it is producing the same error as before. Once tested, try changing the error message as you wish. If things go too wrong, start over or comment out the first 2 lines and the WordPress function will use the old error message.

```
// remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
// add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_115539_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REQUEST variables to know the username used to login, then check if user exist to get his email (which not recommended, as someone may try to get email addresses of users):

```
function my_show_login_error($parm){
    $vars = print_r($_REQUEST,true);
    $my_message = '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Wrong username/password!';
    return $vars;

}
add_filter('login_errors','my_show_login_error' );
```

it shows:

```
Array ( 
    [log] => myuser 
    [pwd] => mypass 
    [otp] => 
    [wp-submit] => Log In 
    [redirect_to] => http://example.com/wp-admin/ 
    [testcookie] => 1 
)
```

Comment: I would **strongly** caution you to not use this on anything but a testing server that only you can see. If nothing else, it's exposing the password that a user attempts to use.

Comment: sure, it is using print_r to show variables only.