# How to give the same error message when the wrong password or wrong username is used?

Tags: security

For security reasons, my WordPress instance should give the same error message when an incorrect password or wrong username is used. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `login_errors` filter for changing the custom error message

Please have a look at

[Change login error messages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution suggested in the accepted answer myself. But it works only if the 'password' input is wrong. The snippet below will echo "Wrong credentials" regardless of wrong password or username. Just sharing something I learned [from here](http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-filter-or-change-wordpress-admin-error-message/). Hope this saves someone a little time.

```
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
function rs_custom_login_error(){
    return $error = "Wrong credentials.";
}
```