# How to translate wordpress error message

Tags: plugins, php, functions, translation

I have a problem and I am not finding the variable to solve, I have a site in WP and when I try to login and neither the password nor the email exists, I get the error message: ERROR: The username or password you entered is incorrect. Lost your password? I tried to find this phrase in wp-login.php but I did not find it, could you help me? Note: I tried to use the loco translate but he does not think that phrase!

I even managed to change the error message, but it is replicating to all other pages, I would like it to appear only on the login page

I tried to make it appear only on the login page this way

functions.php

```
function erroLogin(){
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
function rs_custom_login_error(){
    return $error = "Informações não existem ou estão erradas!";
}
}
```

page.php

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) { ?>
<?php erroLogin(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And I tried that way too.

functions.php

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) { ?>
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
    function rs_custom_login_error(){
        return $error = "Informações não existem ou estão erradas!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which language have you selected in the backend, page "Settings" ?

Comment: Was Português BR

Comment: have you the last wordpress version ? I have try with version 4.9.1 and the language name is "Português do Brasil" and not "Português BR". And after I try with a wrong username, it writes "ERRO: Nome de usuário inválido. Perdeu a senha?"

Comment: É esse erro que me retorna

Comment: https://snag.gy/pI9xeZ.jpg

Comment: it can be the theme which change this. try with the basic theme twentyseventeen

Comment: Delete the other themes, I'm currently using DIV, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem, follow the code in case someone needs the solution:

```
add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

    function login_error_message($error){
        //check if that's the error you are looking for
        $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
        if (is_int($pos)) {
            //its the right error so you can overwrite it
            $error = "Um ou mais campo estão em branco ou dados não existem!";
        }
        return $error;
    }
```

Source from where I located the answer:
[Change login error messages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages)