# Edit incorrect password message WordPress

Tags: php, filters, hooks

I would like to edit the text that is displayed when the user enters an incorrect password on my site. The text is in the location `\wp-includes\user.php`. I have tried editing the file via Filezilla but it says I do not have permission to do so.

The code I would like to change is:

```php
if ( ! wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'incorrect_password',
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: User name. */
                __( '<strong>Error</strong>: The password you entered for the username %s is incorrect.' ),
                '<strong>' . $username . '</strong>'
            ) .
            ' <a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">' .
            __( 'Lost your password?' ) .
            '</a>'
        );
    }
```

Is there a filter I can hook into?

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages). As a rule, never edit core WP files directly, they will be overwritten on the next WP update. There are almost always action/filters you can hook into to do changes.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thank you for your reply. The solution in that post has not worked for me, unfortunately. I also should've mentioned that I only want to delete the "lost your password?" link, not the whole message.